# How to remove one instance of an object name with ".removeWhere" instead of all the elements in a list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart

For example,
Lets say you have a list of apples

```
List<String> apples = ['green', 'red','red', 'yellow']
```

And you want to remove just one red apple using .removeWhere

```
apples.removeWhere((element => element == 'red));
```

however, this removes all instances of 'red' when I only want to remove one of them! Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use directly the `remove` method on your list:

```
   List<String> apples = ['green', 'red','red', 'yellow'];    
   apples.remove("red");
   print(apples); // [green, red, yellow]
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to use it like you're using the `removeWhere` method, you can use this extension method :

Add this on the global scope (outside your classes, just put it anywhere else you want)

```
extension RemoveFirstWhereExt<T> on List<T> {
  void removeFirstWhere(bool Function(T) fn) {
    bool didFoundFirstMatch = false;
    for(int index = 0; index < length; index +=1) {
      T current = this[index];
      if(fn(current) && !didFoundFirstMatch) {
        didFoundFirstMatch = true;
        remove(current);
        continue;
      }
      
    }        
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
   List<String> apples = ['green', 'red','red', 'yellow'];    
   apples.removeFirstWhere((element) => element == 'red');
   print(apples); // [green, red, yellow]
```

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to work the best for me!

Answer (score 1):

A third solution, if you want to remove all occurrences in your `List` so every `String` should be there only once, you can simply make it a `Set` :

```
 List<String> apples = ['green', 'red','red', 'yellow', 'green'];
 print(apples.toSet().toList()); // [green, red, yellow]
```